# How to prevent "collapsing" of table rows on drag and drop using JQuery UI Sortable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I use the following code to make my GridView on an ASP.NET page to support sorting using drag and drop:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#gvJobs").sortable({
            items: 'tr:not(:first)',
            cursor: 'move',
            axis: 'y',
            helper: 'original',
            stack : '#set tr',
            revert : true,
            dropOnEmpty: true,
            receive: function (e, ui) {

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This already works pretty well, but whenever a table row is in dragging mode it gets "squeezed":

[image: squeezed table]
*(on the picture you see that all rows collapsed for the dragged element)*

How can I achieve that the row does not get changed on dragging?

Comment: Try `forceHelperSize: true` and `forcePlaceHolderSize: true`. That's what did the trick for me.  I also made sure that my `handle` was of the same height as the desired height of the dragged element.

Answer (score 1):

Adding [forceHelperSize](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-forceHelperSize)`: true` from the jQuery-UI sortable documentation should solve this problem for you.